# Integrate automated GWT GUI testing with build system

Tags: gwt, build-automation, automated-tests

I am in flux for integrating an automated GUI testing with my build system. My GUI application is developed in GWT. I use [HUDSON](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Home) as my automated build system. I would like to perform sanity test of my application. As I understand, the entire test setup will have following steps.

1. Build and deploy the application in predefined application server. In my case, it would be create and install the application in Android emulator.
2. Start/Launch the application.
3. Perform pre-defined user actions(UI Test cases) and validate them.
4. Somehow include validations for different browsers. I am really not sure how can I do this.
5. Generate report of test cases performed.

I am not posting the details of application as I think this detail will not make any difference in the approach. Can somebody guide me using past experience if this is possible and if it is then to what extent. The best UI automation tool (preferably open source) which can fit easily here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use [TeamCity](http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/) as build server for a GWT application. We just use it as a build server with two tasks: compile sources into Javascript, and deply war file to Tomcat application server. Although I didn't manually set it up yet, I believe it's possible to add a third task for UI testing using [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) (which we used for another JSF web application testing).

A fairly good example of using Selenium automated testing is [RichFaces](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/Richfaces4testplan). If you download its source code package, it includes hundreds of UI-testnig codes written generated by Selenium.

Comment: Mohsen, did you guys use ANT to compile the GWT? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, we used ANT for compilation and creating/deplying WAR file.